# HP P1005 Printer installation problem (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupsext')

Tags: drivers, package-management, printing

I am trying to install hp laser-jet p1005 printer drive for Ubuntu based of [this](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index) instruction.

So i have run the `hplip-3.20.9.run` file and i get this error:
[image]
And by running the 'hp-plugin' command i get this error:

```
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads$ hp-plugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-plugin", line 41, in <module>
    from base import device, utils, tui, module, services
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/device.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import status
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/status.py", line 33, in <module>
    import cupsext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cupsext'
```

I guess my Internet ISP has blocked hp site and the installation process can not download the hp plugin file, so I have downloaded the `hp_laserjet_p1005.plugin` file form [here](https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/hp_laserjet_p1005.plugin), but can not install it (the `hp_laserjet_p1005.plugin` in download folder missed and cannot be selected!):

[image]
Also as you can see below,it fail to download the above plugin:
[image]
Also as you can see below, i have installed python cubs module:

```
sudo aptitude install python-cups
python-cups is already installed at the requested version (1.9.73-2)
python-cups is already installed at the requested version (1.9.73-2)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
                                         
(base) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads$ sudo aptitude install python3-cups
python3-cups is already installed at the requested version (1.9.73-2)
python3-cups is already installed at the requested version (1.9.73-2)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

and my CUPS packages are shown below:

```
apt search cups
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
apcupsd/bionic 3.14.14-2 amd64
  APC UPS Power Management (daemon)

apcupsd-cgi/bionic 3.14.14-2 amd64
  APC UPS Power Management (web interface)

apcupsd-doc/bionic,bionic 3.14.14-2 all
  APC UPS Power Management (documentation/examples)

bluez-cups/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS

boomaga/bionic 1.0.0-1 amd64
  virtual printer for viewing a document before printing

brother-cups-wrapper-ac/bionic 1.0.3-1-0ubuntu4 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for ac brother printers

brother-cups-wrapper-bh7/bionic 1.0.0-10-0ubuntu6 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for bh7 brother printers

brother-cups-wrapper-common/bionic 1.0.0-10-0ubuntu7 amd64
  Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages

brother-cups-wrapper-extra/bionic 1.2.1-0ubuntu4 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for extra brother printers

brother-cups-wrapper-laser/bionic 2.0.1-2-0ubuntu7 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for laser brother printers

brother-cups-wrapper-laser1/bionic 1.0.2-1-0ubuntu9 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for laser1 brother printers

brother-cups-wrapper-mfc9420cn/bionic 1.0.0-1-0ubuntu7 amd64
  Cups Wrapper drivers for mfc9420cn brother printers

cloudprint-service/bionic,bionic 0.14-9 all
  provide a service for sharing printers on Google Cloud Print

collectd-core/bionic-updates 5.7.2-2ubuntu1.2 amd64
  statistics collection and monitoring daemon (core system)

conky-all/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (all features enabled)

conky-all-dbg/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (all features enabled - debug)

conky-cli/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (basic version)

conky-cli-dbg/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (basic version - debug)

conky-std/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (default version)

conky-std-dbg/bionic 1.10.8-1 amd64
  highly configurable system monitor (default version - debug)

cpdb-backend-cups/bionic 1.0.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - CUPS/IPP Backend

cups/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD/driver support, web interface

cups-backend-bjnp/bionic 2.0.1-1 amd64
  printer backend for Canon BJNP protocol

cups-browsed/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - cups-browsed

cups-bsd/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - BSD commands

cups-client/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - client programs (SysV)

cups-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 all [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - common files

cups-core-drivers/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - driverless printing

cups-daemon/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - daemon

cups-filters/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Main Package

cups-filters-core-drivers/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Driverless printing

cups-ipp-utils/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - IPP developer/admin utilities

cups-pk-helper/bionic-updates,now 0.2.6-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  PolicyKit helper to configure cups with fine-grained privileges

cups-ppdc/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation utilities

cups-server-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 all [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - server common files

cups-tea4cups/bionic,bionic 3.13~alpha0+svn3565-4 all
  Swiss Army's knife of advanced CUPS administrators

cups-x2go/bionic,bionic 3.0.1.3-2 all
  Virtual X2Go printer for CUPS

escputil/bionic 5.2.13-2 amd64
  maintenance utility for Epson Stylus printers

etw/bionic 3.6+svn162-3 amd64
  arcade-style soccer game

etw-data/bionic,bionic 3.6+svn162-3 all
  graphics and audio data for etw

foomatic-db/bionic,bionic 20180306-1 all
  OpenPrinting printer support - database

foomatic-db-compressed-ppds/bionic,bionic,now 20180306-1 all [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting printer support - Compressed PPDs derived from the database

foomatic-db-engine/bionic 4.0.13-1 amd64
  OpenPrinting printer support - programs

foomatic-filters/bionic 4.0.17-10 amd64
  OpenPrinting printer support - filters

foomatic-filters-beh/bionic,bionic 4.0.17-10 all
  Openprinting Backend error handler

gimp-gutenprint/bionic 5.2.13-2 amd64
  print plugin for the GIMP

gkrellmapcupsd/bionic 0.02ubuntu1 amd64
  gkrellm plugin displaying the current processor speed

google-cloud-print-connector/bionic 1.12-1 amd64
  Google Cloud Print CUPS Connector

gtklp/bionic 1.3.1-0.1build1 amd64
  printing tool for CUPS on the GNOME Desktop

gutenprint-doc/bionic,bionic 5.2.13-2 all
  users' guide for Gutenprint and CUPS

gutenprint-locales/bionic,bionic 5.2.13-2 all
  locale data files for Gutenprint

hplip/bionic 3.17.10+repack0-5 amd64
  HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)

ippsample/bionic 0.0+20180213-0ubuntu1 amd64
  ippsample - Samples/development tools for the IPP

ksystemlog/bionic 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64
  system log viewer

latencytop/bionic 0.5ubuntu3 amd64
  A tool for developers to visualize system latencies

libcpdb-libs-backend-dev/bionic 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - Development files for Backend Library

libcpdb-libs-common-dev/bionic 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - Development files for both libraries

libcpdb-libs-common0/bionic 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - Interface Library for Backends

libcpdb-libs-frontend-dev/bionic 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - Development files for Frontend Library

libcpdb-libs-frontend0/bionic 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Common Print Dialog Backends - Interface Library for Frontends

libcups2/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library

libcups2-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Development files CUPS library

libcupscgi1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - CGI library

libcupsfilters-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Development files for the library

libcupsfilters1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Shared library

libcupsimage2/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Raster image library

libcupsimage2-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Development files CUPS image library

libcupsmime1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - MIME library

libcupsppdc1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - PPD manipulation library

libfontembed-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Development files for font embed library

libfontembed1/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - Font Embed Shared library

libgtk2-ex-printdialog-perl/bionic,bionic 0.03-3 all
  pure-perl alternative to the Gnome2::Print libraries

libgutenprint-dev/bionic,now 5.2.13-2 amd64 [installed]
  development files for the Gutenprint printer driver library

libgutenprint-doc/bionic,bionic 5.2.13-2 all
  documentation for the Gutenprint printer driver library

libgutenprint2/bionic,now 5.2.13-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  runtime for the Gutenprint printer driver library

libgutenprintui2-1/bionic 5.2.13-2 amd64
  runtime for the Gutenprint printer driver user interface library

libgutenprintui2-dev/bionic 5.2.13-2 amd64
  development files for the Gutenprint printer driver user interface library

libnet-cups-perl/bionic 0.64-1 amd64
  Perl module for printing through CUPS

libreoffice/bionic-updates,bionic-security 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 amd64
  office productivity suite (metapackage)

nagios-plugins-contrib/bionic 21.20170222 amd64
  Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems

printer-driver-brlaser/bionic,now 4-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers

printer-driver-cups-pdf/bionic 3.0.1-5 amd64
  printer driver for PDF writing via CUPS

printer-driver-dymo/bionic 1.4.0-8 amd64
  printer driver for DYMO label printers

printer-driver-escpr/bionic 1.6.17-2 amd64
  printer driver for Epson Inkjet that use ESC/P-R

printer-driver-gutenprint/bionic,now 5.2.13-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  printer drivers for CUPS

printer-driver-hpcups/bionic 3.17.10+repack0-5 amd64
  HP Linux Printing and Imaging - CUPS Raster driver (hpcups)

printer-driver-hpijs/bionic 3.17.10+repack0-5 amd64
  HP Linux Printing and Imaging - printer driver (hpijs)

printer-driver-indexbraille/bionic 1.2.3-1 amd64
  CUPS printing to Index Braille printers

printer-driver-m2300w/bionic,now 0.51-13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  printer driver for Minolta magicolor 2300W/2400W color laser printers

printer-driver-min12xxw/bionic,now 0.0.9-10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  printer driver for KonicaMinolta PagePro 1[234]xxW

printer-driver-oki/bionic,bionic 1.0.1-1 all
  printer driver for OKI Data printers

pyppd/bionic,bionic,now 1.0.2-6 all [installed]
  CUPS PostScript Printer Driver's compressor and generator

python-cups/bionic,now 1.9.73-2 amd64 [installed]
  Python bindings for CUPS

python-stdnum/bionic,bionic,now 1.8.1-1 all [installed]
  Python module to handle standardized numbers and codes

python3-cups/bionic,now 1.9.73-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Python3 bindings for CUPS

python3-cupshelpers/bionic,bionic,now 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
  Python utility modules around the CUPS printing system

python3-stdnum/bionic,bionic 1.8.1-1 all
  Python module to handle standardized numbers and codes (Python3 version)

qpdfview/bionic 0.4.14-1build1 amd64
  tabbed document viewer

qpdfview-djvu-plugin/bionic 0.4.14-1build1 amd64
  tabbed document viewer - DjVu plugin

qpdfview-ps-plugin/bionic 0.4.14-1build1 amd64
  tabbed document viewer - PostScript plugin

qpdfview-translations/bionic,bionic 0.4.14-1build1 all
  tabbed document viewer - translations

roger-router/bionic 1.8.14-2build3 amd64
  Home router management tool - GUI

roger-router-cli/bionic 1.8.14-2build3 amd64
  Home router management tool - command-line interface

ssvnc/bionic,now 1.0.29-3build1 amd64 [installed]
  Enhanced TightVNC viewer with SSL/SSH tunnel helper

system-config-printer/bionic,bionic,now 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
  graphical interface to configure the printing system

system-config-printer-common/bionic,bionic,now 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
  backend and the translation files for system-config-printer

system-config-printer-udev/bionic,now 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Utilities to detect and configure printers automatically

x2goserver-printing/bionic,bionic 4.1.0.0-3 all
  X2Go server (printing support)

xpp/bionic 1.5-cvs20081009-3 amd64
  X Printing Panel

yasat/bionic,bionic 848-1ubuntu1 all
  simple stupid audit tool
```

my OS is :

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**Update:**

> By trying more than 5 times the installation process finally it could
> download the plug in file and it installed!.
> [image]

**new Update :**

**Every** time i connect the printer to My laptop it **trying to install** the **Hp1005 plugin** and i **can not install it easily**, so needs to try **5 or more times** to be installed!!!.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Try install foo2xqx driver:

foo2xqx is an open source printer driver for printers that use the HP/Software Imaging "XQX" stream wire protocol for their print data, such as the HP LaserJet P1005, HP LaserJet P1006, HP LaserJet P1505, and the HP LaserJet M1005 MFP.

Download the driver.

Open a terminal and run:

```
  cd ~/Downloads     
  wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
```

Now unpack it:

```
  tar zxf foo2zjs.tar.gz
```

Now compile and install it.

```
 cd foo2zjs
 make
 ./getweb P1005
```

Install driver, foomatic XML files, and extra files:

```
 sudo make install
```

Configure hotplug

```
 sudo make install-hotplug
```

Restart the spooler:

```
 sudo make cups
```

Now create printer entries for your spooler

```
 system-config-printer
```

Comment: Thank, Now the Printer is working but i will test it on my Ubuntu 20 at future.